# multi-assignment on a Seq[Tuple2]

Tags: scala, collections, tuples, variable-assignment

Flailing around here, seems simple.

Have a `Seq[Tuple2[A,B]]`, call it foo, and I'd like to extract the `Tuple2` into a `(Seq[A],Seq[B])` that I can do a one stop shop multi-assignment on.

```
val(a,b) = foo ??
```

Tried map, flatmap and other variations of fail.

Shed the light if you will ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `unzip`.

The docs specify it as

```
def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: (A) ⇒ (A1, A2)): (Seq[A1], Seq[A2])
```

So you can just say `val (a, b) = foo.unzip`

To go the other way (from `x: Seq[A]` and `y: Seq[B]` to `z: Seq[(A,B)]`), you can use `val z = x.zip(y)`.

Comment: the simple things ;-) Thanks, really useful to be able to break apart nested form mappings in a more meaningful way than "Foo(seq.map(_._1),seq.map(_._2))"

Comment: You're welcome! You just gotta love Scala's standard library :D